# what is the taylor expansion of $\ln(\sin x/x)$

Tags: calculus

what is the Taylor expansion of the function
$$f(x) = \ln \frac{\sin x}x$$
around  the point $x=0$? Ignore powers of $x$ which are greater than $6$.

Here is my method:
$$\ln(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}2 + \frac{x^3}3 -\frac{x^4}4,$$
so we should get the function
$$g(x)=\frac{\sin x}x$$
in the form of $1 + x$ to get the answer … or is there another way to consider the Taylor expansion of $\ln (u)$ by considering $f$ to be the answer of $$\frac{\sin x}x\cdots$$
Which way is the best?? What is the final answer???

Answer (score 6):

$$\begin{align}\log(\frac{\sin x}{x}) 
= & \log\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left( 1 - \frac{x^2}{n^2\pi^2}\right)
= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\log\left(1 - \frac{x^2}{n^2\pi^2}\right)\\
\stackrel{\color{blue}{^{[1]}}}{=} & -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k}\left(\frac{x}{n\pi}\right)^{2k}
\stackrel{\color{blue}{^{[2]}}}{=} -\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k}\left(\frac{x}{n\pi}\right)^{2k}\\
\stackrel{\color{blue}{^{[3]}}}{=} & -\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\zeta(2k)}{k\pi^{2k}} x^{2k}
= -\frac{1}{6}x^2 -\frac{1}{180}x^4 - \frac{1}{2835} x^6 - \frac{1}{37800} x^8 - \cdots
\end{align}$$

***Notes***

$\color{blue}{[1]}$ the power series converges when $|x| < \pi$.
$\color{blue}{[2]}$ legal to change order of summation because all terms have same sign.
$\color{blue}{[3]}$ $\zeta(z) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{-z}$ is the [Riemann zeta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function). When $z$ is an even integer, it can be expressed in terms of [Bernoulli number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number) $B_{2k}$:
$$\zeta(2k) = \frac{(-1)^{k+1} B_{2k} (2\pi)^{2k}}{2(2k)!}$$
Look at the wiki pages for more relations.

Answer (score 3):

As you suggest, it will be useful to know the expansion
$$\ln(1+t)=t-\frac{t^2}{2}+\frac{t^3}{3}-\frac{t^4}{4}+\cdots\tag{1}$$
(at least for $|t|\lt 1$).

We also need the power series expansion for $\sin x$, which is
$$\sin x=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}+\cdots.$$
So the function which is $1$ at $x=0$ and $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ elsewhere has power series expansion 
$$1-\frac{x^2}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{5!}-\frac{x^6}{7!}+\cdots.\tag{2}$$
Now substitute (2) for $1+t$ in (1). Thus $t=-\frac{x^2}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{5!}-\frac{x^6}{7!}+\cdots$.

Make  sure not to compute too far. So throw away all terms in powers of $x$ greater than $6$.

Because the expression (2) has no $x$ term, you will only need to compute to the $\frac{t^3}{3}$ term in (1). So the calculation is less time-consuming than it seems.

Getting a *general* term for the power series expansion looks, however, very difficult. Luckily you were not asked to find many terms. You will end up with something of the shape $ax^2+bx^4+cx^6$.

Answer (score 3):

Your instincts are correct.  Write

$$\frac{\sin{x}}{x} = 1 - \frac{x^2}{6} + \frac{x^4}{120} - \frac{x^6}{5040} + \cdots$$

We wish to maintain the series to $O(x^6)$.  Then

$$\begin{align}\ln{\left ( \frac{\sin{x}}{x}\right)} &=  \left (\frac{\sin{x}}{x} - 1\right ) - \frac12 \left (\frac{\sin{x}}{x} - 1\right )^2 + \frac13 \left (\frac{\sin{x}}{x} - 1\right )^3-\cdots \\ &= \left ( - \frac{x^2}{6} + \frac{x^4}{120} - \frac{x^6}{5040} + \cdots \right ) - \frac12 \left ( - \frac{x^2}{6} + \frac{x^4}{120} - \frac{x^6}{5040} + \cdots \right )^2+\\ &\frac13 \left ( - \frac{x^2}{6} + \frac{x^4}{120} - \frac{x^6}{5040} + \cdots \right )^3-\cdots \\ &= - \frac{x^2}{6} + \frac{x^4}{120} - \frac{x^6}{5040} + \cdots - \frac{x^4}{72} \left (1 - \frac{x^2}{10}+\cdots \right ) - \frac{x^6}{648}+\cdots \\ &= - \frac{x^2}{6} - \frac{x^4}{180}-\frac{x^6}{2835}+\cdots \end{align}$$

Note that

$$-\frac{1}{180} = \frac{1}{120} - \frac{1}{72}$$
$$-\frac{1}{2835} = -\frac{1}{5040}+\frac{1}{720}-\frac{1}{648}$$

Comment: One interesting thing is that we have $$-\frac{1}{2}\left(-\frac{x^2}{6}+\frac{x^4}{120}-\cdots\right)^2\neq $$

$$\neq -\frac{1}{2}\left(-\frac{x^2}{6}\right)^2\left(\frac{-\frac{x^2}{6}+\frac{x^4}{120}-\cdots}{-\frac{x^2}{6}}\right)^2,$$

which seems to look like $$-\frac{1}{2}\left(-\frac{x^2}{6}\right)^2\left(1-\frac{x^2}{20}+\cdots\right)^2$$

$$-\frac{x^4}{72}\left(1-\frac{x^2}{20}+\cdots\right)^2$$

Here $20\neq 10$.

To make this correct, you must use Cauchy product, where $$-\frac{x^2}{6}+\frac{x^4}{120}-\cdots$$

converges absolutely.

Comment: [There's a Cauchy product convergence theorem.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product#Convergence_and_Mertens.27_theorem)

Comment: Your answer is correct, by the way. [WolframAlpha agrees with your answer.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=taylor+series+ln((sin+x)%2Fx))