# $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} \frac {\ln(x)}{\ln( \sin x)}$ without l'Hôpital's rule

Tags: calculus, limits

How to calculate $\displaystyle
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{+}}\frac{\ln x}{\ln (\sin x)}$ without l'Hôpital's rule please?
If anybody knows please help
I don´t have any idea :-( 
I´m looking forward your helps

Comment: Taylor may help.

Comment: **Hint:** Logarithmic identities give you
$\ln(\sin x) = \ln x + \ln\left(\frac {\sin x} x\right)$

Comment: Hint: $\sin x=\dfrac{\sin x}x\cdot x$.

Comment: [See here for how to prove a similar limit $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\ln(\cos (x))}{\ln\left(1-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)} =1$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2442078/prove-lim-x-to-0-frac-ln-cos-x-ln-left1-fracx22-right-1-witho)

Answer (score 2):

If you are allowed to use the limit $\lim_{x\to0}{\sin x\over x}=1$, then you can say

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to0^+}{\ln(\sin x)\over\ln x}&=\lim_{x\to0^+}{\ln x+\ln({\sin x\over x})\over\ln x}\\
&=1+\left(\lim_{x\to0^+}\ln\left({\sin x\over x}\right)\right)\left(\lim_{x\to0^+}\left({1\over\ln x}\right)\right)\\
&=1+0\cdot0\\
&=1
\end{align}$$

(Note, I inverted the limit for the sake of simplicity.  If the answer hadn't turned out to be $1$, it would be necessary to take its inverse.)

**Added later**:  It occurs to me you really don't need to know the limit for $(\sin x)/x$.  All you need is a pair of inequalities, such as

$${x\over2}\le\sin x\le x$$

(for small positive $x$) since that becomes

$$\ln x-\ln2\le\ln(\sin x)\le \ln x$$

so that

$$1\le{\ln(\sin x)\over\ln x}\le1-{\ln 2\over\ln x}$$

when $x\lt1$ (the inequalities reverse because you're dividing by a negative number), and the [Squeeze Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem) now does the rest.  The inequalities bounding $\sin x$ above and below are fairly easy to prove from the geometric definition of the sine function, interpreting $x$ as the arc length along the unit circle.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my approach but feel free to comment.
Let $\frac{\ln x}{\ln(\sin x)}=t$ Then cross multiply gives $\ln x=t \ln(\sin x)=\ln(\sin x)^t$
This can be written as $x=(\sin x)^t$ after taking e-powers. So it follows $\frac{(\sin x)^t}{x}=1$ Recognizing a standard limit, the value for $t$ that works is if $t=1$ and so that would be the answer to the limit.

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to use the Maclaurin series expansions ([see this Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#List_of_Maclaurin_series_of_some_common_functions)) for $\sin x$ and $\ln (1-x)$, then you can compute as follows. Since
$$\sin x= x-\frac{1}{6}x^3+\frac{1}{120}x^5+O(x^7)$$

and

$$\ln(1-x)= -x-\frac{1}{2}x^2-O(x^3),$$

combining both, we have that

\begin{eqnarray*}
L &=&\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{+}}\frac{\ln x}{\ln (\sin x)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow
0^{+}}\frac{\ln x}{\ln x-\frac{1}{6}x^{2}-\frac{1}{180}x^{4}+O\left(
x^{6}\right) } \\
&=&\left[ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{+}}\left( 1-\frac{x^{2}}{6\ln x}-\frac{x^{4}}{
180\ln x}+\frac{1}{\ln x} O(x^{6})\right) \right] ^{-1} \\
&=&\left( 1+0+0+0\right) ^{-1} \\
&=&1.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: If someone needs more help, then to see that $\ln(\sin x)=\ln x-\frac{1}{6}x^2-\frac{1}{180}x^4+O(x^6)$, when it converges and when $\sin x>0$, $x>0$, notice that $\ln(\sin x)=\ln (x)+\ln\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)$ and then prove that $\ln\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)=-\frac{1}{6}x^2-\frac{1}{180}x^4+O(x^6)$. [If someone doesn't know how to do this, then see this question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/467986/what-is-the-taylor-expansion-of-ln-sin-x-x)

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{\ln x}{\ln \sin x }=\frac{\ln x-\ln \sin x}{\ln \sin x }+1=\frac{\ln \frac{x}{\sin x}}{\ln \sin x }+1\rightarrow \frac{\ln 1}{-\infty}+1=1$